# PHP ereg problem

Tags: php, ereg

I upgraded to PHP 5.3 and i got the error: ereg has been deprecated.

What can i use to replace this??

```
function CheckIfAlphaNumberic($text) {
    if (ereg('[^A-Za-z0-9]', $text)) {
        unset ($text);
    }
    return $text;
}
```

Comment: DIE EREG! (I would add "a slow death" but it already is)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`preg_match()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php):

```
function CheckIfAlphaNumberic($text){
    if (preg_match('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#', $text)) {
        unset ($text);
    }
    return $text;
}
```

See also: [Switching From ereg to preg](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/pcook/ch13_02.htm)

Furthermore, you may use `return null;` instead of `unset ($text);`

Answer (score 4):

See what it says on the [php site](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ereg.php):

[image]

It recommends using [`preg_match()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.posix.php)

Comment: +1 Though next time please just quote the text (by preceding it with an `>`) instead of inserting an image :) It's pretty hard to read what the image says as it is resized.

Answer (score 1):

use `preg_match`

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php